# SwiftUI set Text and Image on TabbedView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabbedview) for `TabbedView` it says you can add both a Text and an Image View by using a LayoutView. I'm unable to find any reference to LayoutView anywhere.

This works:

```
.tabItemLabel(Image("image"))
```

And this works:

```
.tabItemLabel(Text("image"))
```

How can I show both like UITabBarItem does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode Beta 3, this has been fixed. Here is an example.

```
.tabItem {
    Image(systemName: "circle")
    Text("Hello")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code to set image and text both in `TabbedView`,

See this post for more info https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/117472

```
TabbedView {
            tabOne()
                .tabItemLabel {
                    Image(systemName: "image1")
                    Text("Tab 1")
            }
            tabTwo()
                .tabItemLabel {
                    Image(systemName: "image2")
                    Text("Tab 2")
            }
        }
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to compile even after replacing `tabOne()` and `tabTwo()` with real views. Can you give a concrete example that works?

Comment: It's a bug in the current beta. The person in the linked post has the same problem.

Comment: I also got stuck into it. Hope this bug gets resolved in the release.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Same issue when you use SF Symbols. Please file a bug using the Feedback-Assistent

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround in [iOS & iPadOS 13 Beta 2 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_ipados_release_notes/ios_ipados_13_beta_2_release_notes):

> **Workaround**: Wrap the views you pass to the modifier in a **VStack**:

```
MyView()
    .tabItemLabel(VStack {
        Image("resourceName")
        Text("Item")
    })
```

Note that it's working for me using local images but not with SF Symbols (for example `Image(systemName: "clock.fill")` won't work).

---

### Update:

This issue was fixed with **Xcode 11 beta 3**. `tabItemLabel` is renamed to `tabItem` and can be used like below:

```
.tabItem {
    Image(systemName: "plus")
    Text("Tab1")
}
```